# Can I use "that would be..." instead of that "would have to be..." tentatively answering a question?

Tags: phrases, phrase-choice

Can I use *that would be...* instead of *that would have to be...* tentatively answering a question? For example:

> Person A: What's your favorite movie.
>
> Person B: **That would be** "Lord of the Rings."

Comment: "That would be" works, but it isn't tentative. It sounds rather confident. "That would have to be" is maybe a little bit more tentative, like you're sorting it out as you answer. "That would probably be" is tentative, but isn't any different than just "Probably 'Lord of the Rings.'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone asks you a question and you answer it using "That would be X", it actually means that whatever you are saying is actually what you really believe. It is not a conditional (verb form). In fact, it's pretty much unconditional.

So, the phrase is what is called pragmatically correct.

Pragmatics: Oxford Dictionary via Google

noun: pragmatics
**the branch of linguistics dealing with language in use and the contexts in which it is used, including such matters as deixis, the taking of turns in conversation, text organization, presupposition, and implicature.**